# Display very Large or Small Numbers in Scientific Notation by Counting the Zero's

Tags: c#

I need a method to get the number of Zeros AFTER the Decimal point when the number BEFORE the decimal point is also Zero. So For example 0.00000000987654 would work out as 8, since there are 8 Zero's after 0.  Turning the Decimal Data type into a string I could then display this in Scientific Notation as 9.87654E9.

The reason I need to do this is so I can iterate very small numbers multiple times producing results too high for calculators.

So for example 0.123456789 Multiplied by 0.1 and iterated a 1000 times. (0.123456789 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 * 0.1 ......) works out at 1.234567890000000000000000000E-1001 using the Decimal Data Type with the full 28-digit precision and displayed in Scientific Notation

I was able to achieve this when working with Factorials. For Example the Factorial of 1000 is 1000 x 999 * 998 * 997 * 996 .... all the way down to 0. This number is too high for calculators so I used iteration to achieve the result to 28-digit precision in Scientific Notation.

For the very large numbers I was successful. I achieved this by getting the number of Digits BEFORE the period:

```
    static int Get_Digits_Before_Period(decimal Large_Number)
    {
        decimal d = decimal.Floor(Large_Number < 0 ? decimal.Negate(Large_Number) : Large_Number);
        // 0.xyz should return 0, therefore a special case
        if (d == 0m)
            return 0;
        int cnt = 1;
        while ((d = decimal.Floor(d / 10m)) != 0m)
            cnt++;
        return cnt;
    }
```

I now need a similar method but one for obtaining the number of Zero's AFTER the period.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post this as the answer but I finally created a program that can iterate very large or small numbers with 28 digit precision. ( For example 2.18961306137446848520669395 E-1376 ) However I cannot be sure that the precision is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The exponent range for decimal is 0 ~ -28, so it cannot represent a number such as 1.234567890000000000000000000E-1001, so I just explain numbers in the valid ranges.

To count the ZERO for a decimal, you can fetch the integer and exponent part of the decimal first

```
var number = 0.00000000987654m;
var bits = decimal.GetBits(number); //0~2 are integer part.
var exponent = (bits[3] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
```

Then reduce exponent by significant digits of the integers to get zero count after the period.

```
var zeros = exponent;
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
      if(bits[i] != 0)
         zeros -= (int)Math.Log10(bits[i]) + 1;
}
if(zeros < 0)
    zeros = 0;
```